# Increment decimal values to next integer value

Tags: shell-script, shell, math

I want to increment the decimal value to next integer value through shell script.

For example:

```
i=**1.6**     then I need to print i=**2**
i=**1.00001** then I need to print i=**2**
i=**1.00049** then also I need to print the value as i=**2**
```

So what ever the case, if the decimal value is greater than even by .00000001 I need to print the value as 2.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. If you want the next integer, whatever the decimal part, below is an answer with `sh`:

```
echo $((${i%.*} + 1))
```

If you want the next integer if the decimal part is more than 0, here is an answer with `sh`:

```
[ -n "${i##*.*[1-9]*}" ]
echo $(( ${i%.*} + $? ))
```

(the first test exits with 1 if `i` has some digit other than 0 after the decimal point, else it exits with 0; `$?` contains the exit value)

Same idea with `bash` which is a bit more readable IMHO:

```
[[ "$i" != *.*[1-9]* ]]
echo $(( ${i%.*} + $? ))
```

Using POSIX `expr`, thus compatible with any shell:

```
expr "${i%.*}" + \( "${i##*.*[1-9]*}" = "" \)
```

Comment: Will fail if `i == 1.0000000`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Why? Next integer is 2.

Comment: OP wants to increment _only_ if the value is _greater than_ the integer part.  1.000000 becomes 1; 1.000001 becomes 2.

Comment: @DopeGhoti the question doesn't say that; it says "_increment the decimal value to next integer value_".

Comment: From the OP:  "if the decimal value is greater than even by .00000001"

Comment: @roaima The question is ambiguous. I will come up with something else.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Answer edited.

Comment: Clever to add the exit code of your test!

Comment: Thank you @DopeGhoti. Not the most readable OTOH, as it requires an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Through `awk` and add `0.5` to the result then `.f` will round it up to nearest number by itself.

```
awk -F\= 'BEGIN{printf("%.f\n", $2+0.5)}'
```

Comment: Consider you have 1.01, this must be rounded up to 2. Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes, it does the same

Comment: With `i=1.01` how are you using your code? The `BEGIN { }` block is being run before `awk` reads from _stdin_ so you must be calling it in some other way.

Comment: Your `awk -F= '$2 !~ /[\.0]+$/{printf( "%.0f\n", $2 + 0.5);next} {print $2}'` fails with `i=1` (apparently it's supposed to remain `1`)

Comment: please see [updated in history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/386069/revisions). BTW OP didn't mention it :  ) so I did rollback until OP clarified if s/he needs it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ '1' -eq "$(echo "$i > ${i%.*}" | bc)" ]]; then
    i=$((${i%.*}+1))
else
    i=${i%.*}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash.

To process an arbitrary amount of decimals we either need a program that allow arbitrary precision like `bc`:

```
$ round(){ bc <<< "a=$1"'; scale=0; b=a/1; if (a==b) a else b+1'; }
$ for i do round "$i"; done
1.0000
2
2
2
```

Or process as text:

```
$ round(){ reg='^([0-9]*)\.0*[1-9]'; [[ $1 =~ $reg ]] && echo "$((${1%%.*}+1))" || echo "$1"; }
$ set 1.0000 1.6 1.00001 1.00049
$ for i do round "$i"; done
1.0000
2
2
2
```